# Implicitly unwrapped optional assign in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In Xcode 8 release version, i found a strange scene.

Here is the code,

```
let implicitlyUnwrappedOptionalString: String! = "implicitlyUnwrappedOptionalString"
let foo = implicitlyUnwrappedOptionalString

print(implicitlyUnwrappedOptionalString)
print(foo)
```

and here is the result:

```
implicitlyUnwrappedOptionalString
Optional("implicitlyUnwrappedOptionalString")
```

These above shows that when i assign a *implicitly unwrapped optional* to a variable without a explicit type, the type will be inferred to an optional type, not the type which it originally is, aka *implicitly unwrapped optional*.

My Xcode has been updated to 8. Anyone can verify the behavior in Xcode 7.x?

The change is due to the Swift version changing or the Xcode?

Comment: Yeah that didn't happened with Xcode 7/Swift 2. I've also noticed this while using the Xcode 8 betas. It's a Swift 3 thing for sure, as the new behavior doesn't depend on the SDK used.

Comment: Related: [Swift 3 incorrect string interpolation with implicitly unwrapped strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537177/swift-3-incorrect-string-interpolation-with-implicitly-unwrapped-strings)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a consequence of [SE-0054 Abolish ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md) which has been implemented in Swift 3. Extract from that proposal (emphasis added):

> However, the appearance of ! at the end of a property or variable declaration's type no longer indicates that the declaration has IUO type; rather, it indicates that (1) the declaration has optional type, and (2) the declaration has an attribute indicating that its value may be implicitly forced. ...
>
> **If the expression can be explicitly type checked with a strong optional type, it will be.** However, the type checker will fall back to forcing the optional if necessary. The effect of this behavior is that the result of any expression that refers to a value declared as T! will either have type T or type T?. For example, in the following code:
>
> ```
> let x: Int! = 5
> let y = x
> let z = x + 0
> ```
>
> … x is declared as an IUO, but because the initializer for y type checks correctly as an optional, y will be bound as type Int?. However, the initializer for z does not type check with x declared as an optional (there's no overload of + that takes an optional), so the compiler forces the optional and type checks the initializer as Int.

In your case, the assignment

```
let foo = implicitlyUnwrappedOptionalString
```

makes `foo` a strong optional, as in the example `let y = x`
from the proposal.

You *could* make `foo` an IUO by adding an explicit type annotation

```
let foo: String! = implicitlyUnwrappedOptionalString
```

but generally you should try to get rid from IUOs in your code,
as stated in the same proposal:

> Except for a few specific scenarios, optionals are always the safer bet, and we’d like to encourage people to use them instead of IUOs.