# Class property with exclamation mark still returned as optional

Tags: swift, option-type

I have a class `ScoreModel` simplified to:

```
class ScoreModel {
    var teamName : String!
}
```

Which could be placed in an `Init()` function since it needs to always be set, but that does not help my understanding of the problem:

I have a `ScoreViewController : UIViewController` where I use the non-optional `ScoreModel`:

```
class ScoreViewController {
    var scoreModel : ScoreModel!
}
```

which is passed using `prepareForSegue`. This is all working but when i want to get the teamName it is returned as optional:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated : Bool) {
    let name = scoreModel.teamName
    print(name) 
}
```

this outputs:

```
Optional("teamNameEntered")
```

But the variable is marked with an exclamation mark in the ScoreModel so it should be unwrapped. Why is it still returning an Optional?

EDIT: 
as requested the prepareForSegue method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ScoreViewController {
        let scoreModel = self.scoreModel ?? ScoreModel()
        destinationVC.scoreModel = scoreModel
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the prepareForSegue code?

Comment: Added the prepareForSegue

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103331/swift-nested-non-optional-structure-gives-optional

Comment: Lesson 1: Don't use implicitly unwrapped optionals

Comment: Thanks i found it, strange that i have to force unwrap my implicit unwrapped optionals. Seems odd

Comment: @Alexander Well, it's not always a choice ;)

Comment: @Keiwan Apart from runtime injection of values (like IBOutlets), there pretty much always is, with good design

Comment: @Alexander Not before all the existing Obj-C frameworks get updated by annotating everything with `nonnull` or `nullable` so that those values don't get imported into Swift as IUOs.

Comment: @Emptyless so just unwrap them safely, or convert them into regular optionals at the site they're obtained

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `scoreModel` is `not non-optional`.

> You can declare optional variables using exclamation mark instead of a
>   question mark. Such optional variables will unwrap automatically and
>   you do not need to use any further exclamation mark at the end of the
>   variable to get the assigned value.

In your case, you can assign `teamName` an optional value or a non optional value. So if it is assigned with an optional value, you need to unwrap it to use.

Comment: Even though it is marked with an '!' I still have to unwrap it? That is strange practice since I would crash my own app if I apply an optional to something I defined to only be non-optional.

Comment: 'teamName` is still optional in your case. You just marked it with `!` for automatic unwrap.

Comment: Yes and the automatic unwrapping part is failing ;) That is the point of my question