# Why does forced uwrapped type with nil not crash when passed to a function argument that has optional type?

Tags: swift, swift3

I don't understand why the type system lets me do this?

In other words **I would expect this to crash when foo is passed to the function**.

```
var foo:String!

func someFunction(_ bar:String?) {
    print("-- \(bar) --")
}

someFunction(foo)

=> writes "-- nil --"
```

Comment: Related: [Implicitly unwrapped optional assign in Xcode 8](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39633481/2976878) – [Swift 3 incorrect string interpolation with implicitly unwrapped Optionals](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39537177/2976878). In Swift 3, if IUOs can be type-checked as strong optionals, they will be.

Comment: @Hamish could you post that as an answer?

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633481/implicitly-unwrapped-optional-assign-in-xcode-8.

Comment: Different question same answer.

Comment: @MartinR That was the first Q&A I linked to ;)

Comment: @Hamish: Sorry, I read that on the phone and did not notice that there are two links :)

Answer (score 2):

As @Hamish so correctly points out here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537558/308189

> If the expression can be explicitly type checked with a strong optional type, it will be. However, the type checker will fall back to forcing the optional if necessary.

And the comment on the answer explains why this question was asked:

> As if it weren't bad enough that you have to use an IUO, now they're less useful and behave contradictorily. If I use one it's because I want it to be implicitly unwrapped. They should be called Schrödinger Optionals from now on. – Andreas

Comment: I voted to close the question because of duplication possibility, I suggest you to close it :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `someFunction` you are printing the optional not String. that's why it is not crashing. if you want to print bar as `String`  you have to unwrap the value.

Comment: I assume that this is not what the OP is asking about, it's about why he should do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
// This line will create variable named foo and type of it will be String! and value of it will be nil.
// It mean i can access this variable is force-wraped so it may dangerous but uses of this variable  without type checking compiler will not give any warning(ignore by compiler).
var foo:String!

// This function will accept `String` value or `nil`. 
func someFunction(_ bar:String?) {
    print("-- \(bar) --")
}

// So calling this function use of `foo`(valued nil) will not give any compiler issue.
someFunction(foo)
```