# Implicitly unwrapped optional from init!() in Swift 3.1

Tags: swift, swift3, initialization, option-type

I'm trying to understand how `init!()` works in Swift. Here's my test:

```
struct InitTest {
    var text: String
    init!(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}

let testResult = InitTest(text: "Hello!")
```

For my understanding, testResult should be of type `InitTest` (unwrapped), but it's actually still `InitTest?`.

How is `init!()` different from `init?()` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InitTest(text: "Hello!")` returns an implicitly unwrapped optional,
which is an optional  that is unwrapped *if necessary.* For example
you can access its properties without explicit unwrapping

```
let string = InitTest(text: "Hello!").text
```

or pass it to functions taking a (non-optional) `InitTest` argument:

```
func foo(_ x: InitTest) { }
foo(InitTest(text: "Hello"))
```

But the assignment

```
let testResult = InitTest(text: "Hello!")
```

makes `testResult` a regular ("strong") optional, see
 [SE-0054 Abolish ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md) and  [Implicitly unwrapped optional assign in Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633481/implicitly-unwrapped-optional-assign-in-xcode-8):

> If the expression can be explicitly type checked with a strong optional type, it will be.

Actually I cannot think of a good reason to define an `init!()` method.

Comment: `let text = InitTest(text: "Hello!").text` works as expected, but `let testResult = InitTest(text: "Hello!"); let text = testResult.text` produces an error: `Value of optional type 'InitTest?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`. Why is `testResult` still optional `InitTest`?

Comment: @RoboRobok: That's what I tried to explain at *"But the assignment ... makes testResult a regular ("strong") optional"* and in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633481/implicitly-unwrapped-optional-assign-in-xcode-8. It is a consequence of SE-0054.

Comment: Sorry, I was too excited and didn't notice your explanation :D

Comment: Thank you for help, once again!