# Why are implicitly unwrapped variables now printing out as some(...) in Swift 4.1?

Tags: swift

Say I have the following code:

```
var aString: String!
aString = "second"
print(aString)
```

This will print out `some("second")`. If I remove the `!` from `String` this will just print out `second`. This addition of `some(...)` never used to happen in Swift 4, why is this suddenly happening now in 4.1? Is there ever a reason that I'd need to keep it as `String!` instead of `String` now?

**EDIT**

Just found a reason to keep the exclamation mark - if I have an if clause without an else, my code won't necessarily know that its been unwrapped. How do I handle this situation:

```
var aString: Int!
let aBool = true
if aBool {
    aString = 2
}

print(aString) // Prints some(2), crashes if I remove the `!`
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537177/swift-3-incorrect-string-interpolation-with-implicitly-unwrapped-strings, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633481/implicitly-unwrapped-optional-assign-in-xcode-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String!` is an implicitly unwrapped optional but it's still an *optional*.

The value will get unwrapped to a non-optional only in situations when it has to be unwrapped, e.g. when being passed to a function that cannot take an optional. However, `print` can accept an optional and `String!` will be treated just as `String?`.

This change actually happened in Swift 3 already as part of [SE-0054](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md).

In your example:

```
var aString: Int!
let aBool = true
if aBool {
    aString = 2
}

print(aString)
```

You should not be using an implicitly unwrapped optional because since it's a `var`, it get initialized to `nil`. You should either handle the unassigned case explicitly by using `Int?`, or, give it a default value:

```
let aString: Int
let aBool = true
if aBool {
    aString = 2
} else {
    aString = 0
}

print(aString)
```

Comment: Even simpler: `let aString = aBool ? 2 : 0`. BTW - why is an `Int` being named `aString`?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, I know, didn't want to to major changes.

Comment: If I have an implicitly unwrapped optional as a value in a dictionary of type `[String : Any]`, it still doesn't unwrap, even though I specify it as the non-optional `Any`. Why is that?

Comment: You can always assign `nil` to a dictionary safely. Getting a value from a dictionary always returns an optional.