# How to handle this: Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.String>.some

Tags: swift, model, swift4, word-wrap

Since Xcode 9.3 I get my string variables in my models wrapped with "Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional.some"

I don't know how this is happening but its ruined my apps!

I create my models like this:

```
struct MyModel {
  var myString:String!
  init(){} // for creating empty instances.
  init(son:JSON){
     myString = son["theStringKey"].string
  }
}
```

Till Xcode 9.3 when I printed my model I got pure string variable from it.

But after Xcode 9.3 it gives me wrapped string inside of Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional.some("MyStringValue")

Any Idea what is this?

Comment: Can you show how you print your model?

Comment: Outside of this being the weirdest `init()` I've seen, it would help to see what the expected JSON payload would look like.

Comment: @Sweeper the print output is exactly like this : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional.some("MyStringValue")

Comment: @Alfi No, I mean the line of code starting with `print(...`. Can you show that?

Comment: @Sweeper: like this: print(MyModel(son: JSONVARIABLE).myString)

Comment: You're using SwiftyJSON. This library has many different accessors for its objects. The one you're using, `.string`, returns an optional string.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/49609528/2976878

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today i have facing same error in Xcode `9.3 V`

Just add option value ?? "" your problem is solved

```
  let paramData:Dictionary<String,Any> = [ PARAM.REQUEST_ID : requestId ?? ""]
```

Here you can pass json replace in dictionary

```
struct MyModel {
    var myString:String!
    init(){} // for creating empty instances.
    init(son:Dictionary<String,Any>){
        myString = son["theStringKey"] as! String
    }
}
print(MyModel.init(son: ["theStringKey":"Harshil"]).myString ?? "")
```