# ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional in init vs later

Tags: swift, swift4

I would like to understand why I don't get `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` when I do `params["bar"] = str` but I get it when I declare `params` with the same force unwrapped variable.

See the playground below:

```
import UIKit

var str: String!

str = "Hello"

var params: [String: Any] = [
    "foo": str
]

params["bar"] = str

print(params)

// ["bar": "Hello", "foo": Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.String>.some("Hello")]
```

Comment: Because `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` counts as `Any`. Why would it be coerced (and forcefully unwrapped) to `String`? `String` is not more `Any` than IUO is.

Comment: @Alexander so why is it different for “bar” then?

Comment: Good point. Interesting!

Comment: What version of Swift is this? IUO doesn't exist in 4, and I can't reproduce this in 3.0.1 on linux

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/49609528/2976878. In the case where you're doing `params["bar"] = str`, `Dictionary`'s `subscript` takes an `Optional` value, which (in Swift 4.1) an IUO can be implicitly converted to, or (in Swift 4.2) an IUO is. The value is removed if the optional is `nil`, otherwise the unwrapped value is inserted into the dictionary.

Comment: You can get the same result for `bar` by explicitly casting `str as Any` when making the assignment: `params["bar"] = str as Any`.  This makes `"bar": Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.String>.some("Hello")` instead of `"bar": "Hello"` because in that case the optional is not unwrapped before assigning the value to the dictionary.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your comments, I'm using Xcode 9.4 with Swift 4.1. I just noticed that there was a regression in my app because of this, using  Alamofire and URLEncoding. @Hamish is this the same explanation as the one you linked? Feel free to answer and I would glady accept this, thanks!

Comment: @allaire Sorry for taking so long to get back to this; I've posted an answer :)

Comment: Look at Swift 4.2 : Abolish ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional type

Proposal: SE-0054

Comment: @Hamish Please give this answer i got same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50617135/core-data-appears-to-lose-data-after-xcode-upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 4.1, when you do:

```
var str: String!

str = "Hello"

var params: [String: Any] = [
    "foo": str
]
```

The `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` (IUO) value is coerced to `Any`, which is why it appears as an IUO inside your dictionary. It won't be force unwrapped, because the compiler will only force unwrap an IUO when the context demands its unwrapped type, which isn't the case with `Any`.

However the fact that you end up with an `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` *value* is legacy behaviour. With the removal of the IUO type in Swift 4.2, you'll get an `Optional` value inside your dictionary instead, which will print as `Optional("Hello")`.

There's more discussion of the above behaviour in this Q&A:

- [Why does implicitly unwrapped optional not unwrap in dictionary of type [String : Any]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49609528/2976878)

When you do:

```
params["bar"] = str
```

You're using `Dictionary`'s `subscript(key: Key) -> Value?`, which takes an `Optional` value – performing a removal if `nil` is passed, otherwise doing an insertion of the unwrapped value.

- In Swift 4.1, the IUO value `str` will be implicitly converted to an `Optional` which can then be passed to the subscript.
- In Swift 4.2, the IUO type has been removed, so `str` already *is* an `Optional`, which can be passed straight to the subscript without any intermediate conversions.

In both cases, `str`'s unwrapped value is inserted into the dictionary, which is why you see it as being unwrapped. If `str` had been `nil`, no value for the key `"bar"` would have been inserted.