# Core Data Appears to Lose Data After Xcode Upgrade

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

For the second time, my core data app has "lost" (explanation below) the data. I'm not positive this has to do with the update of Xcode, but I did update to 9.4 today (I don't remember whether there was an update involved the last time this happened). I entered data yesterday, then closed the app, re-opened the app, and everything was fine; all the data was there. Today when I opened the app, there was no data. My app prints out the location of the database (print(container.persistentStoreDescriptions)), and when I look at the sqlite file there it has 25 kB.

Searching through the ridiculously deep folder path, I found a file that said it was modified yesterday, and when I look at the sqlite file there (with DB Browser for SQLite), the data is all there (also 25 kB). It seems as if Xcode has forgotten where it put the data. Has anyone else experienced this?

How would I go about fixing this? I guess I could copy the SQLite database from where it actually is to the place Xcode thinks it is (the other files there also, .sqlite-shm and .sqlite-wal?).

Comment: What is the size of file `.sqlite-shm` and `.sqlite-wal`? Did you copy those files to the location of .sqlite before load the files in DB Browser for SQLite?

Comment: The size of those files doesn't seem to be consistent. Today, the -shm is 33 kB in both the real location, and the location where Xcode thinks the database is. The -wal is zero bytes today, but I remember it being quite large yesterday. I have not moved or copied any files yet. One other thing I noticed, is that after the update of Xcode, the device that initially ran was iPhone 8, whereas, I had been running it on an iPad simulator before the update; not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: `I have not moved or copied any files yet.` This may be the issue. I have faced same problem, When I copied all files(-shm,-wal) to the folder(which one has the .sqlite file OR copied all files including sqlite file into Desktop), then DB Browser showing all tables correctly even sqlite file is too small. Read somewhere:  -shm, -wal are sqlite supported files which have committed changes but may / may not be written to sqlite file.

Answer (score 0):

`after the update of Xcode, the device that initially ran was iPhone 8, whereas, I had been running it on an iPad simulator before the update`

Each simulator gets its own folder with its own sqlite files. So if you want to see the data that was in the iPad simulator before, you need to run the same iPad simulator from the new Xcode. If you copy sqlite files from one simulator folder to another, be sure to copy the -shm and -wal files too.