# Unexpected "some()" in implicit unwrapping using nil coalescing in swift 4.1

Tags: swift, swift4.1, xcode9.3, forced-unwrapping

I experienced a strange response from xcode 9.3 running swift 4.1 while running this code:

```
let old = "not an int"

let new: Int! = Int(old) ?? 2

print(new)

print(new!)
```

Response is `some(2)` and `2` (with forced unwrapping) (check image below).

Where is this `some` coming from? (please explain or provide reference to read more about `some`)

[image]

Comment: Why would you declare `new` as `Int!` instead of just `Int` since it can't be `nil`?

Comment: I know, but I was trying it out, so "some" caught my attention,

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/49609528/2976878

Comment: @Hamish that doesn't explain what "some" means

Comment: @NabeelKhan I expanded my answer slightly; does it answer your question now?

Comment: @NabeelKhan After a long look on everything in the Apple Docs, I can't seem to find **anything** about implicitly unwrapping optionals and why it outputs `some()`, very strange it is not clearly written why anywhere for anyone to see. Very strange...

Comment: @Hamish yes, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`some` is like `optional` is added to optional values when printing them it's new in swift 4.1

Comment: can you please provide reference?

Comment: `.some(wrapped)` is one of the the two cases that define `Optional<Wrapped>`.

Answer (score 1):

When you declared a variable marking it as unwrapped means `compiler` will think there is always `some` value instead of `Optional` which means the value can be nil.

`some` indicates there is always a value but its not `unwrapped` yet.

Comment: its documented logic? or you made it up yourself? it's good though! :D

Answer (score 0):

`let new: Int!` is an `Optional<Int>`, that just happens to be implicitly unwrapped everywhere its used where an `Int` is expected.

`print` takes an `Any...`. `Optional<Int>` is just as much of an `Any` as `Int` is. There's no reason for implicitly unwrapping to be done, and so it isn't.

Comment: Unfortunately it's slightly more nuanced than that; in Swift 4.1, `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` is still a type that exists, and is used by the compiler. The `some(2)` is its `description`, as given by Swift's default reflection mechanism. `Optional` on the other hand customises its `description`, and prints as `Optional(2)` instead (this is behaviour you'll get with IUOs in Swift 4.2 once the IUO type has been fully banished from the type system, but it's not quite yet the case in 4.1).

Comment: @Hamish Interesting! Could you cook that up in an answer? Let me give you internet points

Comment: Over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49708550/2976878 :)

Answer (score 0):

The Optional type is an enumeration with two cases. Optional.none is equivalent to the nil literal. Optional.some(Wrapped) stores a wrapped value. 
[Reference.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional)

[Other information about optionals that might be useful](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) (search for Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals)