# IUO's as dictionary keys in Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, swift4.2

The following code no longer behaves in Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10) the same it was behaving in Swift 4.1 (Xcode 9.4.1):

```
let key: String! = "key"
let dict: [AnyHashable:Any]? = ["key":"value"]
let val = dict?[key]
```

In Swift 4.1, `val` receives the dictionary value ("value"), while in Swift 4.2 it's nil.

The problem goes away if I remove the *Implicitly unwrapped optional* (IUO), or declare the dictionary as `[String:Any]`, so both

```
let key: String = "key"
let dict: [AnyHashable:Any]? = ["key":"value"]
let val = dict?[key]
```

, and

```
let key: String! = "key"
let dict: [String:Any]? = ["key":"value"]
let val = dict?[key]
```

result in `val` ending up holding the string "value".

Is this an intended behaviour in Swift 4.2, or it's a compiler bug?

Asking as I have a huge codebase where both the key and the dictionary come from Objective-C code which is kinda resistant to change. So I was wondering if this change in behaviour is permanent and I should start updating the many places in code that use this pattern, or just wait until a stable build of Xcode 10 is released.

Comment: A lot changed with respect to IUOs in the last releases, compare https://swift.org/blog/iuo/ or the Xcode release notes or https://stackoverflow.com/q/39537177/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39633481/1187415. In most cases, they are handled like regular (strong) optionals. – I wonder *why* you want an IUO as dictionary key.

Comment: I wonder why you are using IUOs at all. They are not deprecated, but their legitimate use is now highly restricted. If `key` is not an instance property it probably should never have been an IUO to begin with.

Comment: @MartinR both the key and the dictionary come from Objective-C, and I don't have too much control over those.

Comment: @Cristik: That might be useful context to add to the question ...

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the suggestion, added this this to the question

Comment: Even better: Show a (minimal) concrete example of  Objective-C code and how it is used from Swift. Perhaps the problem can be fixed by adding the appropriate (non)nullable annotations on the Objective-C side.

Comment: @MartinR both Objective-C callees are simple class methods, I have thought about nullability, however there are lots of classes that would need it, and the effort would be huge...

Comment: @Cristik The situation sounds parallel to the situation with UIViewController's `view`, which is a `View!` and there's nothing you can do about it. I solve the problem by unwrapping: `let v = self.view!`. Now `v` is an ordinary `View` and we can go about our business happily. I believe that's the solution proposed in the answer you've already received.

Comment: @matt yeah, that's another approach.

Comment: "So I was wondering if this change in behaviour is permanent and I should start updating the many places in code that use this pattern, or just wait until a stable build of Xcode 10 is released." If that's the question, my reply would be: this is not a bug, this change is not going away, the proposal has gone through and has been implemented, it's a Good Thing, and you need to adapt or die. :)

Comment: @matt honestly, I'd rather have the lots of Objc code die (or kill it) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has been a proposal [SE-0054](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md) which **has been implemented completely** in Swift 4.2. In the past, there was a type `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` which functioned differently from Swift 4.2 (now all the IUOs are of the `Optional` type in Swift 4.2, not `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`).

From the proposal (emphasis mine):

> If the expression can be explicitly type checked with a strong
>   optional type, it will be. However, **the type checker will fall back to
>   forcing the optional if necessary**. The effect of this behavior is that
>   the result of any expression that refers to a value declared as T!
>   will either have type T or type T?. For example, in the following
>   code:
>
> ```
> let x: Int! = 5
> let y = x
> let z = x + 0
> ```
>
> … x is declared as an IUO, but
>   because the initializer for y type checks correctly as an optional, y
>   will be bound as type Int?. However, the initializer for z does not
>   type check with x declared as an optional (there's no overload of +
>   that takes an optional), so the compiler forces the optional and type
>   checks the initializer as Int.

In your case, the `key` variable is inferred to be of type `String?`, so you still have to cast it. This code would work:

```
let val = dict?[key!]
```

`val` has the value `Optional("value")`

As for why `[String:Any]` works, according to the emphasised part in the quote, `String?` can't be used on `String` , so the compiler will force unwrap it (necessary to let it compile).

Comment: As further evidence of this point, if you create your dictionary with `let dict: [AnyHashable:Any]? = ["key":"value", Optional("key"): "value2"]`, you will see that `dict?[key]` selects `value2`, and `dict?[key!]` selects `value`.

Comment: Wondering then why the compiler unwraps the IUO automatically if the dictionary is `[String:Any]`

Comment: @Cristik: *"However, the type checker will fall back to forcing the optional if necessary"*

Comment: @Cristik in other words, `String?` can't be used on `String`, so the compiler will force unwrap it.

Comment: Thanks! So this is clearly an intended behaviour, and I should start fixing the code right away.

Comment: just a suggestion why don't we apple get rid of IUO and just have optionals ( ? ) in place. To me IUO sounds pretty confusing especially in the examples section of ( https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md ) where the type changes automatically depending on what operation is performed which is dangerous. Also for dev what would be the good practice just to get rid of all the forced bang ! and just use ? optional types ? ( exceptions for IBOutlets ). Please can you help.