# Swift 5: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyObject?' and 'UIView?'

Tags: ios, swift

I working with Swift 5 and trying to test all `NSLayoutContraints` of `someView` if they are relates to some `otherView`:

```
@IBOutlet var someView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var otherView: UIView!

for constraint in someView.constraints {
    if (constraint.firstItem == otherView) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This code fails with the following error:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'AnyObject?' and 'UIView?'

There are quite a few other questions about typing and operators in Swift but I still to not understand why this error occurs and how to solve it:

- `constraint.firstItem` is of type `AnyObject?`. So it either be `nil` or an object of type `AnyObject`
- `otherView` is of type `UIView!`, so it is guaranteed to be not `nil`, correct?

As far as I know `AnyObject` is protocol to which all classes implicitly conform. Thus comparing any object to `AnyObject?` should not be a problem, should it?

**So, why does `constraint.firstItem == otherView` not work and what is the *correct* way to solve it?**

**Bonus question:** Why does the error message speaks of `UIView?` instead of `UIView!`

Comment: For your “bonus question” see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/39633481/1187415.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use **`===`** instead of **`==`**, i.e.

```
if (constraint.firstItem === otherView) {
   ....   
}
```

> **===(*:*:)**
>
> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether two references point to the same object instance.
>
> This operator tests whether two instances have the same identity, not the same value. For value equality, see the equal-to operator (==) and the Equatable protocol.

Answer (score 2):

You're dealing with *optionals* which need to be unwrapped, and you are trying to compare objects which are better compared with `===` which tests if the two references point to the same object.

I would suggest:

```
func doSomething() {
    guard let otherView = otherView else { return }
    for constraint in someView.constraints {
        guard let firstItem = constraint.firstItem else { continue }

        if firstItem === otherView {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** You can use `===` to compare two *optional* references, but it will return `true` if they're both `nil`.

---

Based on @MartinR's discussion below, you could use a mixed approach to avoid the case where both values are `nil` by just unwrapping the first:

```
func doSomething() {
    guard let otherView = otherView else { return }
    for constraint in someView.constraints {
        if constraint.firstItem === otherView {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

---

> otherView is of type `UIView!`, so it is guaranteed to be not nil, correct?

No, it is not guaranteed not to be `nil`.  It will just crash if you use it in a place that expects a `UIView` if it is `nil`.  An *implicitly unwrapped optional (IUO)* is still an *optional*.  It *can* be `nil`.  The only special treatment an IUO gets is that you can use it in places the non-optional type is expected and Swift will unwrap it for you.

Comment: `===` can also compare *optional* object references.

Comment: @MartinR, well, look at that!  Of course, if they're both `nil` they'll compare as equal so you might not want that.

Comment: I was about to leave a comment when you deleted your answer :) –   `otherView` is an IUO outlet, so one can expect that it is not nil. I think there are multiple valid approaches, e.g. a mixed one: Unwrap `otherView`  beforehand, but not `constraint.firstItem`.

Answer (score 1):

In Obj-C it would work, as the isEqual is looked up during runtime.
In Swift it has to be a concrete type during compile tine.

```
for constraint in someView.constraints {

    if let view = constraint.firstItem as? UIView {
        if (view == otherView) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```