# Optional in file path Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3

In swift3 I have problem to access local files that I downloaded then unzipped.

The path contains "Optional":

```
  Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/..../data/Containers/Data/Application/...
/Documents/Optional("folder-name")/Optional("file-name")
```

My code to create this path is:

```
let videoPath = fileManager!.appendingPathComponent("\(MyObj.folder)/\(MyObj.fileName)")
SpeedLog.print(videoPath.path)
```

The class MyObj is:

```
class MyObj : NSObject, NSCoding {
var fileName:String!  
var folder:String!

required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init()
    self.fileName = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "fileName") as! String
    ....
}
convenience init(id:Int,fileName:String,...) {
    self.init()
    self.fileName = fileName
    ....
}
func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
    if let fileName = fileName { coder.encode(fileName, forKey: "fileName") }
    ....
}
```

How to build the path without "Optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing "Optional" in your string output means you're passing in an *optional*, a variable that might contain a value or might contain `nil`. If you're certain that it isn't `nil` when you want to use it, you can *force unwrap* it by adding `!` to its name, which makes it no longer optional. If you do this to a variable that is `nil`, you'll get a runtime error. Alternatively you can unwrap using `let`.

```
var optional:String?            // optional, contains nil
print(optional)                 // 'nil'
optional = "something"          // still optional, contains "something"
print(optional)                 // 'Optional("something")'
print(optional!)                // 'something'
let nonOptional = optional!     // not optional, contains "something"
print(nonOptional)              // 'something'
```

There's a lot more about optionals in the [Swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).

In the MyObj class definition you provided it looks like the `fileName` and `folder` instance variables are set up as *Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals* (they have an `!` after their names when they are defined), which used to work fine but is now giving you this problem.

In Swift 3 Apple made changes to the way Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals work, which is the cause of your problem here. There's a full explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537558/149097), but the short version is that string interpolation no longer treats them as implicitly unwrapped.

The workaround is to manually unwrap them using `!`, or use a different method to build your string. You can concatenate strings and string literals using the + operator, which I think looks pretty clean:

```
let path = obj.folder + "/" + obj.fileName
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. In fact MyObj is a instance of MyObj, I just renamed it in the example given. So I changed to fileManager!.appendingPathComponent("\(MyObj.folder!)/\(MyObj.fileName!)") and it works, but I do not really understand why I need to add ! as before it was working and there is already ! in the Class definition

Comment: @Ludo Actually it looks like you did everything right but Apple changed the way Swift handles implicitly unwrapped optionals in string interpolation. I added an explanation and an alternate way of creating strings to my answer.