# Swift3 : unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I ve just upgrade from Swift 2 to Swift 3, and i m facing a new challenge...

I have a player which run perfectly before, but now i have this following issue :  "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Here is my code :

```
print(audioselectionne)

let alertSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: audioselectionne as String, ofType: "mp3")!)
```

I ve got : Optional("tiesto") and the crash...

I really dont understand where is the issue...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The issue is you force unwrapped the return of `pathForResource` but it was nil; the resource wasn't found.

Comment: yes but i have changed nothing and it was working with Swift 2

Comment: Why do you have the downcast `as String` ?  Remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `Bundle.main.path` method returns an optional `String`. When that’s `nil` (because the resource was not found), force-unwrapping it causes your error. If you want to handle it correctly, you have to check for the `nil`:

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(…) else {
    // resource not found, handle error
}

// now `path` is guaranteed to be non-nil
let alertSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
```

Comment: the problem is why with Swift3 , it doesn't find the file ? it's pretty weird

Comment: Maybe the path comes out different from your previous code in Swift 3, but the error you get _is_ caused by the force-unwrap (`!`). Don’t force-unwrap values unless you _have_ to.

Comment: Actually, if this is supposed to be in Bundle.main.path then you shouldn't handle the error but fix either the path or make sure the resource is there.

Answer (score 1):

You should unwrap the optional, perhaps with optional binding.

BTW, you shouldn't be use path strings at all anymore. Just use the URL directly, e.g.

```
guard let resource = audioselectionne, let alertSound = Bundle.main.url(forResource: resource, withExtension: "mp3") else {
    // handle file not found here
    return
}

// use alertSound here
```

Comment: audioselectionne coming from a prepareforsegue and declared like this var audioselectionne:String?

Comment: i guess it s same probleme here...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537177/swift-3-incorrect-string-interpolation-with-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals

Comment: "File not found"? That's very different from "unexpected found nil". I was answering the unwrapping the optional question (and advising you to follow Apple's guidance to shift from paths to urls). If the file is not found, then that file is just not in your bundle. Is this file in the bundle or the documents folder?

Comment: Actually, when i do : let alertSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "tiesto" as String, ofType: "mp3")!). It's working perfectly. But when i m trying to input my variable; audioselectionne, , it doesn't work. Think it's an issue with uwrapping the optional ...

Comment: That's why I did `guard let resource = audioselectionne, let alertSound = ...`, that way, I'm unwrapping the `audioselectionne` optional first, and then using that in `Bundle.main.url(...)` call...

Comment: and i did. but same problem... In fact, i add print("not working...") between guard let ...... and return. And guess what happens when i m running the app...