# Optional displayed on label since Swift 3 upgrade

Tags: swift3

My code was working perfectly with Swift2 and now for some label the variable is displayed but with Optional(....) just before...

Good code on Swift 2

```
var sstitre1:String!
 print(sstitre1)
```

There is a perform segue which populate a value to sstitre1.

```
    var sstitre1:String?

    sstitre1 = json[21].string


 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "hugo"
    {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? MonumentViewController{

            destinationVC.sstitre1 = "\(sstitre1)"

        }

    }
}
```

With Swift3, i ve get :
Optional(.....)

I want to get rid of Optional.

So i have as recommend on several post from stackoverflow, made some code change.

var sstitre1:String!

```
If let espoir = sstitre1 {
print (espoir)
}
```

But unfortunately it still displays Optional....

Pretty weird ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 incorrect string interpolation with implicitly unwrapped Optionals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537177/swift-3-incorrect-string-interpolation-with-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals)

Comment: Yes it s same issue but i didnt get a proper way to deal with it.

Comment: How are you assigning `sstitre1`? Sounds like you're baking the `"Optional(...)"` into the string itself.

Comment: The value coming from a previous screen via performsegue

Comment: @Hugo75 Then please show us that code.

Comment: As suggested in the linked article you have explicitly to unwrap the optional : `print(sstitre1!)`. However the best way to get rid of that problems is to use non-optionals.

Comment: @vadian : error: cannot force unwrap value of non optional type string

Comment: Then the issue comes from an earlier String Interpolation of an optional somewhere else

Comment: @Hamish, you will find additional code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
destinationVC.sstitre1 = "\(sstitre1)"
```

always a literal string `"Optional(foo)"` is assigned to `destinationVC.sstitre1` assuming the variable contains `"foo"`

The solution is to remove the String Interpolation

```
destinationVC.sstitre1 = sstitre1
```

PS: You should really use more descriptive variable names

Comment: Will try this, btw its descriptive for me and in french ;)

Comment: you definetely rock ! and i will amend sstitre1 ;)