# Implicitly unwrapped optional in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am newbie for Swift and I have question about Implictly Unwrapped Optional on Swift.
And sorry for unpretty format, I'm also newbie for stackoverflow.

```
let x: Int! = 1
print("\(x)")
```

Above Swift codes print "Optional(1)".
I think that should print "1" since the constant "x"`s type is "Int!" rather than "Int?" to implicitly unwrap from followed codes.
But it prints "Optional(1)".

I ran that code on [IBM Swift Sandbox](https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl).

What's wrong with it?﻿

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39537558/1271826

Comment: In Swift 3 the behavior for implicitly unwrapped optionals has changed. While in Swift 2 the optional got always unwrapped when used, in Swift 3 the IUO will get converted to a normal optional when possible.

Comment: Thanks for comments all!