# Convert swift 2.3 to swift 3 error

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift2, xcode8.2

i convert swift 2.3 to swift 3 in xcode 8.2

swift 2.3: Is there code, Is there code, Is there code, Is there code, Is there code

```
func playAudio() {
    self.stopAudio()
    let lessonObject:LessonObject = self.lessonArray[self.selectedIndex] as! LessonObject
    let fullPath:String! = Constants.URL_HOST + "\(lessonObject.lessonPath)"
    let soundURL:NSURL! = NSURL.init(string:fullPath)
    let documentsDirectoryURL =  NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
    let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(soundURL.lastPathComponent!)
    if NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath(destinationUrl!.path!) {
        if let soundData = NSData(contentsOfFile: destinationUrl!.path!) {
            self.initAudioWithData(soundData)
        }
        else {
            self.audioErrorAction()
        }
        return
    }
    
    if let soundData = NSData(contentsOfURL:NSURL(string:fullPath)!) {
        self.initAudioWithData(soundData)
    }
    else {
        self.audioErrorAction()
    }
}
```

swift 3: Is there an error in the code?

```
        func playAudio() {
        self.stopAudio()
        let lessonObject:LessonObject = self.lessonArray[self.selectedIndex] as! LessonObject
        let fullPath:String! = Constants.URL_HOST + "\(lessonObject.lessonPath)"
let soundURL:URL! = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: fullPath)
        let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(soundURL.lastPathComponent)
        if FileManager().fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path){
            if let soundData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: destinationUrl.path))
            {
                self.initAudioWithData(soundData)
            }
            else {
                self.audioErrorAction()
            }
            return
        }
if let soundData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string:fullPath)!)
        {
            self.initAudioWithData(soundData)
        }
        else {
            self.audioErrorAction()
        }
    }
```

after convert my error:

> found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.
>
> I build swift 2.3: destinationUrl = "file:///Users/admin/Library/.../Documents/test.mp3" 0x00006080002a73e0
>
> I build swift 3: destinationUrl = "file:///Users/admin/Library/.../Documents/Optional(%22test.mp3%22)"

Comment: which line report the error?

Comment: if let soundData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string:fullPath)!)

Comment: If you already have `destinationUrl` as a `URL`, why do you create a new URL from its `path`? Just do `if let soundData = try? Data(contentsOf: destinationUrl)`.

Comment: What kind of URL is `fullPath`?

Comment: @TuanKenz, clearly `fullPath` is not valid url string, can you paste it here? And in future try to avoid using `!`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `init(fileURLWithPath: String)`? instead of `init(string: String)`?

Comment: Anyway, If the file does not exist, why are you trying to load the data?

Comment: @TuanKenz, why not use `soundURL` then, instead of converting path to url  twice?

Answer (score 0):

The source of the error is in this line

```
let fullPath:String! = Constants.URL_HOST + "\(lessonObject.lessonPath)"
```

First of all – however not related to the issue – do not annotate types the compiler can infer. You turned a *good* non-optional string into a *worse* implicit unwrapped optional.

The property `lessonPath` is apparently an (implicit unwrapped) optional, too. Using String Interpolation you get literal `"Optional(foo)"`. You need to unwrap the optional or use optional binding if the property could be `nil`. Consider a non-optional property if the value can never be `nil`

```
let fullPath = Constants.URL_HOST + "\(lessonObject.lessonPath!)"
```

For further information read [Swift 3 incorrect string interpolation with implicitly unwrapped Optionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537177/swift-3-incorrect-string-interpolation-with-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals/39537558#39537558)

**Never ever declare properties as implicit unwrapped optionals 
  to avoid to write an initializer**.