# Swift NSObject property is not optional , but it prints optional

Tags: ios, swift, forced-unwrapping

```
let allPlaces = resultsArray.map({ (param) -> Places in
                        return Places(dictionary: param )
                    })
                    print("All Places \(allPlaces[0].placeName)")
```

The output of the above code is:

> All Places Optional("Subway")

In the below code the var is not optional. But the print statement prints it as Optional. Should it not print **All Places "Subway"**?

```
class Places: NSObject {


    var name:String!


    init(dictionary:Dictionary<String, Any>) {

        name = dictionary["name"] as? String
    }
}
```

Comment: From this place dictionary["name"] as? String it's giving optional. Changing it to dictionary["name"] as! String will give you non-optional

Comment: Try this `print("All Places " + allPlaces[0].placeName)`

Comment: `dictionary["name"] as? String` makes it optional value.

Comment: See [Swift 3 incorrect string interpolation with implicitly unwrapped Optionals](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39537177/2976878) – an IUO is treated as a strong optional wherever it can be type-checked as one.

Comment: Whenever you put `!` or `?` in front of a "type", it is actually an `Optional` type. The only difference is that you are telling the compiler that when you read the `name` property you don't want to handle its nullability ('cause you are sure it won't ever be `nil`), but it still could be `nil`. Said this, you can simply define the property as `var name:String`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var name:String!
```

You have declared name as implicitly unwrapped optional. From `Swift 3` onwards it will **only be force unwrapped if they need to be type checked locally**. Otherwise it will be treated as normal optional only.

```
 print("All Places \(allPlaces[0].name)")
```

Here there is no type checking involved, so name would be still Optional.

If you do like

```
let name:String = allPlaces[0].name
print("All Places \(name)")
```

Output will be "All Places Subway"

or you need to force unwrap it

```
 print("All Places \(allPlaces[0].name!)")
```

This would cause crash if the `name` is nil, you should take care of it. If there is a chance name can be nil then use `var name: String?` so compiler force you to unwrap explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

**Change 'as?' to 'as!'.**

- The exclamation point means it absolutely clear.
- The question mark means optional binding.

**[Source]**

```
class Places: NSObject {


    var name:String!


    init(dictionary:Dictionary<String, Any>) {

        name = dictionary["name"] as! String 

    }
}
```

**Another way**

```
print("All Places \(allPlaces[0].placeName)")
```

**to**

```
print("All Places \(allPlaces[0].placeName!)")

or

print("All Places \(allPlaces[0].placeName ?? "")")
```

Comment: what is the  difference between below answer @theodore cha

Comment: What if "name" key is not available?

Comment: @andyPaul i think.. use 
Double question mark (set default value)  // name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""

Comment: @andyPaul 
Double question mark : if value is not available, save default value ("")

Comment: @VinodKumar I added other ways.

Comment: now it fine@theodorecha