# Why is array inferring optional type for implicitly unwrapped elements?

Tags: swift, option-type

Consider following example:

```
let a: Int! = 1
let b: Int! = 2
let array = [a, b]
print(type(of: array)) // prints: Array<Optional<Int>>
```

Why is inferred type of the array `[Int?]` and not `[Int]` or `[Int!]`? I thought implicit unwrapping deals with optional for good, at risk of runtime error. But in order to get non-optional `[Int]` type for the array, I need to do one of the following manually:

```
let array1 = [a!, b!]
let array2: [Int] = [a, b]
let array3 = [a, b] as [Int]
```

Comment: Compare: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39537177/1630618

Comment: Hmm, interesting. So far same goes with Swift 4.