# Declare NSMutableArray content type

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, nsmutablearray

I have a piece of code I've used in an objective c app that I want to incorporate into a new swift project. Problem is I can't work out the syntax!

I'm using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) to get some information about sets of cards from a sql database. When I pull the information out of the database I create a card object which has properties described in the database. When I access the database it returns an `NSMutableArray` of my card objects. I want to explicitly state that my mutable array contains these objects...

I would do this in objective c by writing:

```
NSMutableArray<Card*>
```

I'm using it in this context

```
- (NSMutableArray<Card *> *)getCardsFromDb
```

So I know my function is returning a mutable array of `Card` objects. How can I do this in swift?

at the moment the code in my project is minimal

```
   //Properties
    var cardArray: NSMutableArray<Card>! //How can I tell it that the array is populated with my Card object?

    //View Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess()

        cardArray = databaseAccess.getCardsFromDatabase()

        print(cardArray)

    }
```

For the moment I've just called the array a temporary name because I was just testing that the database methods worked. I have tried `NSMutableArray[Card]` and `NSMutableArray(Card)` but neither worked.

I would like to do this so that I know when making the database call I am getting an array of card objects, not just some random array.

Thanks

Comment: Is a Swift array `[Card]` what you are looking for? – You did read the chapter about [collection types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) in the "Swift Programming Language" reference, didn't you?

Comment: The best solution is to use a Swift array instead of `NSMutableArray` (or `NSArray`).

Comment: @MartinR I was not familiar with this (thanks) but it doesn't solve my problem as I lose the methods associated with `NSMutableArray` to add the card details to my card object as I iterate through the sql database.

Comment: @Axemasta What methods do you mean? A Swift array has many, many ways to modify and iterate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to declare a variable of type `array of Card` but not save an array into it, you'd use

```
var cardArray: [Card]
```

That's equivalent to the Objective-C

```
NSMutableArray<Card*> cardArray;
```

(Or rather, the Objective-C is equivalent to the Swift, since Objective-C adopted typed arrays in order to be compatible with Swift.)

If you want to define a variable of type `array of Card` and put a blank array into it, you'd use

```
var cardArray = [Card]()
```

That's equivalent to

```
NSMutableArray<Card*> cardArray = [NSMutableArray new];
```

(Although I forget how you satisfy the type requirement in Objective-C. That Objective-C statement might need minor tweaking...)

Comment: OP can't declare `var cardArray: [Card]` as a property of his view controller without initializing it unless he declare its type as optional or IUO which wouldn't make any sense in this case.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks for the clear explanation! I've converted every instance of `NSMutableArray` with my object array `[Card]`. My database getter function now returns `[Card]` so I can properly use this when I come to populate a tableview with data. Many Thanks!

Comment: Yes, as Leo points out I should have mentioned that if you declare a non-optional property of a class then you need to give it a value at some point before initialization completes. You can either give it a default value when it's declared or give it a default value in the initializer. The effect is pretty much the same.

Comment: The ObjC line at the end is correct (except that you're missing the variable name itself!) -- there's no parameterization on the name of the class in the invocation, just the variable's type.

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks for catching the missing variable name. Does the result of the call to `new` need to be cast to type `NSMutableArray<Card*>` to satisfy the compiler's type checking?

Comment: No, no need to cast. The generics aren't that significant.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are writing Swift code, you should declare `cardArray` as:

```
var cardArray: [Card] = []
```

instead of:

```
var cardArray: NSMutableArray<Card>!
```

Because `getCardsFromDatabase()` returns a mutable array (not Swift array), you would need to down cast it first before assign it to `cardArray`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess()

    cardArray = databaseAccess.getCardsFromDatabase() as! [Card]

    print(cardArray)
}
```

Comment: Why implicitly unwrapped optional? It doesn't make any sense its usage here

Comment: @LeoDabus `cardArray = databaseAccess.getCardsFromDatabase() as! [Card]` is that what you mean?

Comment: Do you know the difference between IUO and forced casting? I am talking about `var cardArray: [Card]!`

Comment: @LeoDabus honestly, I'm not pretty sure that I got it right, is it related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537177/swift-3-incorrect-string-interpolation-with-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals ? please advice.

Comment: Just initialize the array with an empty array instead of declaring it as `[Card]!`

Comment: @LeoDabus Edited. I think it wouldn't be different in this case, is it correct? thank you in advance :)

Comment: You should avoid using  implicitly unwrapped optionals as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty behind on my swift and am usually referring to projects I've done in objective c. A better solution was to get my function to return a `[Card]` array so that I dont have to cast anything when using the function.

Comment: @Axemasta if you were able to change the implementation of `getCardsFromDatabase ()` that would be true, you don't even have to deal with `NSMutableArray` at all.

Comment: @AhmadF Yes thats what I ended up doing. I did this thing on an objective c app, now I try to do everything in swift and was just copying along what I had previously done! I'll keep in mind that I should not be using `NSMutableArray` in swift, if I can help it!