# Swift remove optionals and unnecessary characters iOS

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to storing struct values into array and same array I want to store it into User-default and retrieve to show tableview.

```
struct item:Codable {
    var title : String!
    var size : String!

    init(title: String, size: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.size = size
    }
}
```

I am using below method for storing

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(items), forKey:"items")
```

And get it back

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"items") as? Data {
   let items_user = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array<item>.self, from: data)
   print("*************\(String(describing: items_user))")
}
```

But output getting

```
Optional([ZLib.item(title: Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.String>.some("con-smash.gsheet"), size: Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.String>.some("120 KB"))])
```

How to remove above `optional` and `ZLib.item(`, `Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.String>.some(` unnecessary info.

Comment: Related: [Swift 3 incorrect string interpolation with implicitly unwrapped Optionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537177/swift-3-incorrect-string-interpolation-with-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all struct names are supposed to start with a capital letter

Just remove the exclamation marks in the struct.

**Never declare members / properties as IUO if there is an initializer with non-optional values**.

```
struct Item : Codable {
    var title : String
    var size : String

    init(title: String, size: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.size = size
    }
}
```

Second of all

**Never use `value(forKey` with `UserDefaults`**.

In this case there is a dedicated method `data(forKey` otherwise use `object(forKey` or other dedicated methods for scalars (`integer(forKey`, `bool(forKey` etc.). However this is not related to the issue.

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey:"items") {
```

Finally `catch` always errors when using `Codable` and don't misuse the `String(describing` initializer

```
  do {
      let itemsUser = try PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array<Item>.self, from: data)
      print("*************", itemsUser)
  } catch { print(error) }
}
```

To get rid of the app name in a `print` statement adopt `CustomStringConvertible` and add your own `description`

```
struct Item : Codable, CustomStringConvertible {
    var title : String
    var size : String

    init(title: String, size: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.size = size
    }

    var description : String {
        return "title : \(title), size : \(size)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant answer!

Comment: Wow Awesome. great explanation and answer. I learned from you. Thank you so much I will mark it and one more doubt I am getting [ZLib.Item(title: "con-smash.gsheet", size: "120 KB")] is it possible to remove ZLib? i think its app name @vadian

Comment: Great,Sorry to asking you again I am appending into table data array 

    var items = [Item]()
    items.append(Item(title: filename, size: string)) is it possible to give                         items.append(itemsUser)? if i give I am getting Cannot convert value of type '[Item]' to expected argument type 'Item' @vadian

Comment: You can assign the array directly `items = itemsUser` or if you don't want to overwrite existing data `items.append(contentsOf:itemsUser)`

Comment: I am getting empty array by items.append(contentsOf:itemsUser) after append I am doing like let item = items[indexPath.row] ,cell.name_label_util.text = item.title in cell for index @vadian

Comment: Do you call `tableView.reloadData()` after the `append` line? You have to. And please no *snake_cased* variable names. According to the naming convention it should be `nameLabelUtil`

Comment: tableView.reloadData() yes I am doing but nothing cell showing in my tableview @vadian

Comment: If `print`ing `itemsUser` shows the data then the cause of the issue is somewhere else and beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "`String`" instead of "`String!`" to avoid "Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional.some(" being printed.

`try?` means you will get an optional object so you get  "Optional([ZLib.item(......"

you can try this:

```
do {
    let items_user = try PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array<item>.self, from: data)
} catch {
//error
}
```

or:

```
let items_user = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array<item>.self, from: data)
```